# How do i add a list of numbers together from a text file?

Tags: c#

I have a text file containing numbers both negative and positive and want them to display the total in a TextBox. The text file is arranged as follows

- 0
- 25
- 25
- -10
- 67.5
- 33.33
- -45

and so on. There can be different numbers on each line both positive and negative and to 2 decimal place at the most. I'm sure its quite simple but I don't know how to do it. Can anybody help?

Comment: There are many different ways to do this.  You will need to narrow down the scope of what you are asking.  Are you stuck opening and reading from the file, are you stuck with parsing the numbers, shows us some code and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total = Directory.EnumerateFiles ("C:\\", "*.txt")
                     .Select (filePath => File.ReadLines (filePath)
                                              .Select (x => decimal.Parse (x))
                                              .Sum ())
                     .Sum ();
```

Of course this code needs some improvements (error handling, parsing etc.).

Comment: Nice shrinking :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have text files with contents 1,3,33,-44.3 in each files on D drive. You can try this

```
decimal total = 0;
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("D:/", "*.txt"))
{
  string content = File.ReadAllText(file);
  total += Convert.ToDecimal(content);
}
```

Comment: This will only work if there is only one number in each file. If the file contains more than one number this will fail (if it contains a number a newline and a number it will throw an exception).

Comment: @pstrjds yes i have mentioned in the answer

Comment: Your answer only works in the case where each file contains only one number and no other text aside from whitespace.  This is why the question itself is ambiguous and has too many possible answers.